Are bare screw-heads on air-fryer food-safe?
I just bought my first air-fryer - it appears to be a reputable brand, perhaps on the cheaper end.
The Teflon-coated "basket" (bowl) is attached to the plastic handle by a number of screws. I was shocked to see that the screws are mounted so the heads of the screws are inside the basket. The curve of the basket is such they aren't even flush - the heads stick out at an angle.
I am worried about food getting caught in the threads and other cracks and being impossible to adequately clean. I am trying to work out if I am being overly-sensitive, or this is a legitimate food safety issue.
Product photo below is of the replacement part, showing the bowl and screws, and where the screws go.


I've seen similar attachments on saucepans, though rivets are more common, so it's not a one-off

@ChrisH: If I saw that, I would ask the same question. It seems very unhygienic to me, but I am prepared to be told my intuition is off.

I wouldn't worry about the threads in the ones I've seen because of seals under the heads. Probably not yours either; those captive washers should make a decent seal given that you're not filling an air fryer with soup.  I'd be more worried about stuff not washing out of the heads or the screw recesses very well, whether with a brush or a dishwasher.  But still not very worried.

Given the operating temperatures, it's unlikely to be a food safety issue, as anything that grows there is going to get killed in use.

@Ecnerwal: Is that an answer? Please use the answer box where it can be voted, edited, accepted, etc.
